# Need to display MessageBox before further Server Side Processing

Tags: javascript, vbscript, asp-classic

I have an asp application which gets **strVar** as part of Request from calling asp and it executes the **SQL Script** based on input parameter. This application works as required. I need to make changes so that **a message box is displayed on the browser seeking confirmation to progress**. Based on confirmation, the SQL Script should be executed. Please find below the code of ASP page (DBUpdate.asp):

```
<%@ Language=VBScript.Encode%>
<%   
Option Explicit
' -- Declare Variables
Dim objConn                     ' Our Connection Object
Dim objRS                           ' Our Recordset Object
Dim strSQL                        ' Our SQL String to access the database
Dim strConnection            ' Our Connection string to access the database
Dim i                               ' a counter variable
Dim stVar                       ' Doc ID 
' -- Retrieve Doc ID
stVar = Request.QueryString("strVar")
Response.Write "Variable - " & stVar
' -- Create objects
Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
' -- Connection String Value
strConnection = "DSN=TESTDB"
' -- Open the Connection
objConn.Open strConnection %>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showMsg()
{
  var temp = confirm("Please confirm!");
}
</script>
<% 
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
**'Need Help Here .. How to show a message box to get a confirmation dialog**
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Response.Write "Value of variable temp is " & temp
if stVar <> "" then
  strSQL = "UPDATE Table1 SET Var2 = 1 WHERE Var1 = " & stVar
  set objRS = objConn.Execute (strSQL)
end if
set objRS = Nothing
set objConn = Nothing
%>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>DB UPDATE</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I tried to add  a java script function as shown below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function showMsg()
  {
    var temp = confirm("Please confirm!");
  }
</script>
```

But, I am not able to get the value of variable *temp* in the asp code.

**EDIT**

This ASP file is being called by a different application and I do not have access to it. I have omitted the contents of  tag in the example. Initially, following used to happen:

1. Calling application will make a call - `http://<servername>/utilities/DBUpdate.asp?strVal=123`
2. DBUpdate.asp will execute the SQL Script
3. DBUpdate.asp page will be shown

New requirement is following:

1. Calling application will make a call - `http://<servername>/utilities/DBUpdate.asp?strVal=123`
2. *A confirmation pop-up should be displayed.*
3. DBUpdate.asp will execute the SQL Script based on confirmation
4. DBUpdate.asp page will be shown

Comment: Do you really want to send the boolean value to the server, or do you want to cancel the request to the server entirely based on the boolean value?  More to the point, where are you attempting to use it?  How does the page make the request to the server?

Comment: I want to cancel the request to server based on the Boolean value.

Comment: I also tried to add a hidden element. Amend its value in Java Script and access the value in classic asp using Request.Form(<element id>). But, the value is not available in the classic asp

Comment: Then start with whatever is making the request, since that's what you want to change.  You're not showing that in the question.  If it's a form post or a link click for example, there are many examples online showing how to use a `confirm()` to prevent a form post.

Comment: It is not possible to amend the calling application as I do not have access to their source code.

Comment: Then how did you "try to add a hidden element"?  How are you adding a `confirm()` in the first place?  You're being very inconsistent in what you're describing/asking, which makes the problem very unclear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153284/discussion-between-abhineet-and-david).

Comment: updated the description of the question

Comment: Ok, the updated description definitely clarifies.  In this case what you want is to basically have *two* pages.  (Or at least a page that expects two requests.)  The "pop-up" is really just the first page.  No JavaScript is required.  (Unless the decision really is that it *needs* to be a "pop-up", which is just silly.)  The first page is nothing but a form which is populated by the `strVal` value (potentially in a hidden form element) and a submit button asking for the confirmation.  That work would then post to the DB update page you already have.

Comment: I created my test harness just the way you have suggested i.e. a text box for strVal and a Submit button.
Unfortunately, it is required to display a "pop-up" at run-time.

Comment: In that case you can still add a pop-up `confirm()` to that form.  Seems silly to make the user click something twice though.  It sounds like whoever is defining the requirement could use a basic user experience session on the matter.

Comment: @David - Thanks for your recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to pass a variable from javascript to server side asp. Hence, I used David's suggestion to resolve this issue.

Below are the details:

- Move the code from DBUpdate.asp to a new ASP file
- Use the existing DBUpdate.asp to show the pop-up
- Based on the confirmation do a HTTP GET to the new ASP file
- Further details present in DBUpdate.asp are being routed to the
  calling application